# WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service /usr/bin/safaridriver

Tags: macos, robotframework, safaridriver

While I'm trying to run my robot framework automation script in mac through command window(python -m robot users.robot), I'm getting an exception as follows:

**WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service /usr/bin/safaridriver**

Any help would be appreciated

Safari version:12.0

Pycharm version: Pycharm 2018.2.4(community edition)

```
    *** Settings ***
    Resource  ../settings.robot

    *** Variables ***
    ${user_profile}         css=#dropdownMenuUser > div
    ${drop_down_menu_user}  css=body > app-root > div > div.flexRowStatic > twine-header > div > div > div.flexColumnStatic > ul > li:nth-child(2) > user-icon > div > ul
    ${role}                 css=body > app-root > div > div.flexRowStatic > twine-header > div > div > div.flexColumnStatic > ul > li:nth-child(2) > user-icon > div > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a
    ${sys_admin}            css=body > app-root > div > div.flexRowFill.flexColumnContainer > div.flexColumnFill > admin > div > div:nth-child(1) > h2

    *** Keywords ***
    Click on the user profile icon
      Click Element "${user_profile}"

    Verify that the user profile pop up menu is displayed
      Element Should Be Visible  ${drop_down_menu_user}
```

Comment: Can you provide your code

Comment: Have provided my code

Comment: Is there any more to that error message?

Comment: How are you opening the browser? Can you create a [mcve] that shows an example that opens the browser and then generates this error?